# Longest consecutive downfall in financial series

Tags: r, finance

I would like to ask you for help regarding an issue which seems really weird. Namely, I am trying to find the longest consecutive subsequence of negative returns in a financial time series (and when it occured), but I can manage to program only longest consecutive subsequence of returns with the same sign. I am dealing with the following type of financial data:

```
               LgReturn
1991-08-13  0.005180647
1991-08-14  0.008555806
1991-08-15  0.004878436
1991-08-16 -0.004723199
```

My approach was the following: First use sign to get sequence of only 1s (positive return and -1s (negative return) and use rle
to get the list of all lengths of appearances

```
z <- sign(NASDAQLgRetOpen[,1])
rle(z)
```

The command rle(z) produces the following output:

```
Run Length Encoding
lengths: int [1:2731] 3 3 2 1 4 6 1 1 2 3 ...
values : num [1:2731] 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -1 1 -
```

Then I used the following code to find the longest subsequence:

```
pad <- rev(sort(rle(z)$lengths[rle(z)$values[rle(z)$lengths]==-1]))
```

and the following code to extract the  position at which it occurs in my time series

```
vsota <- sum(rle(z)$lengths[1:(which(unlist(rle(z)$lengths)==pad[1]))])
```

This gave me the rows in my time series, so I used

```
serija <- NASDAQLgRetOpen[(vsota+1-pad[1]):vsota,1]

plot(cumprod(1+serija), type="l")
```

The problem is that I get a plot, which clearly shows an increasing sequence, so I have found the longest positive subsequence. What is really odd is that I get the positive subsequence regardless whether I choose 1 or -1 in the line

```
 pad <- rev(sort(rle(z)$lengths[rle(z)$values[rle(z)$lengths]==-1]))
```

What am I missing? Please guys, help me out, since this is really confusing. Thank you in advance for your suggestions.

...found an easy way solve this: reverse the signs and apply log, so that negative returns become 0 and pozitive returns become NaN - then rle always returns longest sequences of negative seturns since Nan is interpreted as of length 1. The following code works; it is assumed that the data you want to analyze are in i-th column of a datatable:

```
fall <- function(data,i){
sg <- log(-sign(data[,i]))
zacetek <-  sum(rle(sg)$lengths[1:(which(rle(sg)$lengths==max(rle(sg)$lengths))-1)[1]])
podatki <- data[(zacetek+1):(zacetek+max(rle(sg)$lengths)),1]
plot(cumprod(1+podatki), type="l")
}
```

Now that this is settled I would ask what is even more important for my data analysis: I have collection of 27 financial data sets and in order to improve my coding skills I would like to start using lapply function instead of for loops or something similar. 
The question is the following: how do I apply the upper function fall on all of my 27 elements in a list. I have used this code to make a list of all objects

```
sz <-c()
for (i in 1:length(files)){
sz <- rbind(sz,gsub(" ","",  paste(unlist(strsplit(files[[i]],
".txt")),"LgRetOpen","")))           
}
sz <- list(sz)
```

to produce the (first lines) of the following result:

```
     [,1]                      
[1,] "AUDUSDLgRetOpen"         
[2,] "BVSPUSDIBOVLgRetOpen"    
[3,] "DAXLgRetOpen"            
[4,] "DJIALgRetOpen"
```

The data on which I want to apply function fall are stored as the names in the sz list, but without the hyphens, i.e. I want to apply fall on AUDUSDLgRetOpen[,1], or better said call function fall(AUDUSDLgRetOpen,1) and so on for each element os the list. How do I do this? I have tried something like

```
padci <- lapply(sz, function(x,i) fall(x,1))
```

but that of course does not work since I have to call data.frames AUDUSDLgRetOpen and so on and not characters "AUDUSDLgRetOpen". How to solve this?

Comment: Are you looking for longest Drawdown or just longest sequence of negative returns?

Comment: Longest sequence of negative returns - the longest drawdowns can be obtained from PerformanceAnalytics package. Do you see where I got it wrong in the code I provided?

Comment: It's not a good idea to add a new question to the bottom of an existing one. If you have a new, different question; it's best to open a new thread.

Answer (score 6):

I think you're on the right track with `rle` but you need to be looking at the values of the run to make sure it's negative. (Of course you need to make sure your data is sorted by date for `rle` to work.)

```
set.seed(17)
dd<-data.frame(
    date=seq(as.Date("1991-01-01"), as.Date("1991-02-28"), by="1 day"),
    lgreturn=rnorm(59, 0, 100)
)

run<-rle(dd$lgreturn<0)

maxrun <- which.min(run$lengths * run$values*-1)
datestart <- sum(run$lengths[1:(maxrun-1)])+1
dateend <- datestart+run$lengths[maxrun]-1
```

Then `datestart` and `dateend` will have the index of the rows where your run begins and ends. And here's a plot of the result...

```
plot(lgreturn~date, dd)
abline(h=0, lty=2, col="red")
abline(v=dd$date[c(datestart, dateend)], lty=2)
```

[image: longest negative streak]

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I cant really see why this code works - why do your diff(use dd$return)<1 and how to account for the fact that my returns are in decimal forms? I have tried your code on my data, but the computer simply froze while plotting. Can you see a way to transform my code so that it would work?

Comment: @user3612816 oops. That's a typo. it should be `diff(dd$return)<0`. `diff` looks at pairwise differences so i'm just trying to find those that are negative to indicate a decrease.

Comment: @user3612816 I see now that your data was in a different format. I've updated my answer accordingly. The trick to finding negatives was doing both `rle(dd$lgreturn<0)` to look for runs of T/F and `which.min(run$lengths * run$values*-1)` to find the largest negative run.